# cannot find symbol variable ic_launcher

Tags: java, android, android-studio, import, wear-os

I am trying to build an empty default project in Android Studio for Android Wear. I get this error:

```
Error:(23, 41) error: cannot find symbol variable ic_launcher
Error:Execution failed for task ':wear:compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

I am a total newbie in wearable app development. Any pointers would really help.
[image]

P.S.: I have done no single change in the code.

Comment: @EdwardvanRaak thanks that worked. Can you please write it as a solution so other people can use it as well?

Comment: Newer versions of Android Studio put the default ic_launcher in the mipmap folder, which is the new best practices place to put launcher icons.  https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/02/14/goodbye-launcher-drawables-hello-mipmaps/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your drawable folder is empty. Put an icon in there with the name "ic_launcher"

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively just reference the mipmap resource by calling `R.mipmap.ic_launcher`

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the "ic_launcher" icon from mipmap-hdpi folder to drawable folder. I had the same issue and it helped!